# R.T.P. σ(p^n)=(p^(n+1)-1)/(p-1). (where σ denotes the divisor function) For a prime p.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum

I need to prove that for a prime p, σ(p^n) is (p^(n+1)-1)/(p-1).

E.g.

σ(3^3) is (3^(3+1)-1)/(3-1).

=3^(4)-1/2

=80/2

=40

Therefore σ(3^3)=40.

Let me know for any suggestions,proofs or references.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The divisors of $p^n$ are $1, p, p^2, \cdots, p^n$.

$$\sigma(p^n)=1+p+p^2+\cdots+p^n=\frac{p^{n+1}-1}{p-1}$$

Comment: Very good...........